# What happen to my Design? Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android

On my previous question 
[Android Missing design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512207/android-studio-missing-design/48512228#48512228) yes I have found my design tab. But why this shows up?

[image]

Any idea what I did wrong here?

A newbie in Android Studio btw.

Answer (score 0):

your parent view is ConstraintLayout, did you try adding constraints to your child views? you can let Android Studio assign constraints automatically using the Infer Constraints [infer constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977540/infer-constraints-in-android-studio-latest-version3-0)